# How to exclude custom global variable in SonarQube for Python (rule S3827)

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, salt-stack

SonarQube has rule python:S3827 - **"Variables, classes and functions should be defined before being used"**.

I am developing [Salt module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/index.html) and code has calls like
`__salt__["cmd.run"](bar)` or `__grains__['kernel']`.
There are other well known variables in Salt modules (`__utils__, __pillar__`, etc).

Obviously I am getting issues from SonarQube because of "`__salt__ is not defined. Change its name or define it before using it`"

[image]

Is there a way to add such variables to the exceptions for the rule S3827 ?